# SCCM manual client install: ccmsetup.exe does nothing

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2, sccm

I'm trying to deploy SCCM on Hyper-V to push updates to Windows 10 clients. When I try to manually install the SCCM client on Windows 10, the installer does nothing.

I've tried connecting to the server via the command line and running ccmsetup.exe in this way, and I've tried copying the entire client folder to the client PC and running the setup this way. The only thing that happens is that Windows is asking for administrator rights, and when I click 'yes', nothing happens.

I checked the task manager to see what happens, and ccmsetup.exe appears in my process list. However, it disappears a few seconds later.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're not supplying any information to the executable to install the client. The minimum you need for most cases are the following:

```
CCMSetup.exe /mp:[1] SMSSITECODE=[2] FSP=[3]
```

Ignore the brackets above during CMD, but

- [1] - The name of your Management Point server - e.g. SMSMP01
- [2] - The SITE Code for your SCCM estate. e.g. S01
- [3] - The name of your Fallback Status Point, e.g. SMSFP01
  Adding `/logon` will abort the installing the client if one already exists on the machine

Gives you: `CCMSetup.exe /mp:SMSMP01 SMSSITECODE=S01 FSP=SMSFP01`

When the client is already installed, you can repair it by simply double-clicking the ccmsetup.exe as you were...

I got this from an MS Docs page, which has more in-depth information:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/core/clients/deploy/about-client-installation-properties